Pseudo Orbital motion only due to Coriolis force
Planet, say of mass M and radius R is rotating with some angular velocity ω and a object of mass m (initially on the surface and rotating with the planet) was launched with velocity v vertically upwards with respect to the planet.
Since, the Coriolis force will be perpendicular to the object's velocity (in the rotating frame of the planet) in theory it should be possible for the object to complete a say "pseudo orbit" in the planet's frame.
Although it becomes difficult when solving for v if we consider the ω×R component to the initial velocity as well. A solution not considering this component will also be highly appreciated.
Is this solvable considering Newtonian gravity? 
Note: Observer is at the initial position of the object.

This is certainly possible.  However, it's much easier to visualize what happens by thinking about the inertial frame first.
Specifically, if an observer launches a projectile "vertically upwards" from the equator of the planet with speed $v$, then in the inertial frame its initial velocity will have a radial component of $v$ and a tangential component of $R \omega$.  If the overall velocity $|\vec{v}| = \sqrt{v^2 + R^2 \omega^2}$ is "just less" than escape velocity, then the object will get extremely far from earth and take a very long time to come back down (Kepler's Third Law.)
In the rotating reference frame, this orbit will appear to "lag behind" the rotation of the Earth as it gets higher and higher, since its angular momentum $\ell = m r^2 \dot{\phi}$ is conserved and $r$ is increasing.  As it reaches the apogee of its orbit ($r = r_\text{max}$), it will have a very small angular velocity in the inertial frame. This means that in the rotating frame, it will appear to have an angular velocity of slightly less than $\omega$ opposite the rotation of the Earth, and will spend a long time "orbiting" the Earth with $r \approx r_\text{max}$ and $\dot{\phi} \approx - \omega$.
The higher the apogee is, the more rotations the Earth will make during the flight of the projectile, and so the more "orbits" the projectile will appear to make in the rotating frame.  It is not hard to see that the number of orbits can be made arbitrarily large by making the $r_\text{max}$ arbitrarily high.  However, it is not possible to get the object to permanently enter a "pseudo-orbit" around the Earth in this way.

Thanks a lot for clarification! I sort of did think of this.
But when I tried to solve it, I had to introduce 6 variables to describe my system. But I only have got 3 equations describing my system. One from constraint, another from angular momentum conservation and the last one from energy conservation. I gave it a lot of thought and I think this way of solving it not really viable. Because in the end there will be too much of a mess left for me to simplify and that too only if I somehow am able to make functions relating all the variables first.
Should i used Lagrangian formulation?

@Kyathallous: What do you mean by "solving it"?  In principle you could find some solution $\vec{r}(t)$ for the motion in the inertial frame, and then it would be easy to port it to the rotating frame via $\theta' = \theta -\omega t$.  That said, since it's not possible to solve $\vec{r}(t)$ for the inertial frame without transcendental functions, a solution of the form you're looking for may not exist.

I see, I was doing the same. I found out the elementary time derivatives of the relative position vector between the observer and the object. The reason I say 'elementary' is because they are laced with too many variables. I have been trying to reduce them to possibly in a single or maybe even in two variables functions but have not had any success so far. But one thing I did realize is that the solution requires solving a case of the two-body problem (where one body is stationary) in a rotating frame. I think it would be possible to modify the solutions accordingly and get an answer. @Michael

How to calculate escape velocity
actually you can look at escape velocity


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In the case you are asking about:
Describing the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system requires more than the coriolis term; the centrifugal term is necessary too.
In total three terms are necessary for the case you are asking about: the term that describes gravity, the centrifugal term, and the coriolis term.


However, it is interesting to examine the following specific case: a case where the centripetal force that is present is such that the centrifugal term and the term for the centripetal force drop away against each other.


Diagram 1.
Motion subject to a centripetal force (animated GIF)
In the animation the dot represents an object, moving frictionless. The arrow represents the centripetal force that the object is subject to.
This animation is for the case such that the centripetal force increases linearly with distance to the point of attraction. (That is, this centripetal force is according to Hooke's law.)
The left hand side shows the motion relative to the inertial coordinate system. The right hand side shows the view as seen from a rotating coordinate system that is rotating with the same period as the orbit of the object.

The motion of an object subject to a force according to Hooke's law has remarkable symmetries.
As we know, when the restoring force is according to Hooke's law then the resulting motion is harmonic oscillation.
With two degrees of freedom, as is the case for the motion depicted in the animation, we can think of the motion as two perpendicular harmonic oscillations, at right angles to each other.
The motion of the black dot is according to the following parametric expression:
$x = a \cos(\Omega t)$
$y = b \sin(\Omega t)$
$a$ half the length of the major axis
$b$ half the length of the minor axis
$\Omega$ 360 degrees divided by the duration of one revolution
(Here the capital letter $\Omega$ is used to represent a uniform angular velocity.)
To set up for transformation to the rotating coordinate system as represented in the animation: rearrange as follows:
$$ x = \frac{a+b}{2} \cos(\Omega t) + \frac{a-b}{2} \cos(\Omega t) $$
$$ y = \frac{a+b}{2} \sin(\Omega t) - \frac{a-b}{2} \sin(\Omega t) $$
After transformation of the motion to the rotating coordinate system the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system is as follows:
$$ x = \frac{a-b}{2} \cos(2 \Omega t) $$
$$ y = - \frac{a-b}{2} \sin(2 \Omega t) $$
That is, the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system is perfectly circular, and proceeds at a frequency of $2\Omega$, twice the frequency of the rotating system.
We can think of the perfect circular form of the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system as a symmetry property of motion subject to a force according to Hooke's law.


I will refer to the circle of the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system as the 'epi-circle'.
I will use the lowercase $\omega$ for the angular velocity relative to the rotating coordinate system.
with:
$a_c$ centripetal acceleration wrt to center of epi-circle
$r$ radial distance to center of epi-circle
$v_r$ velocity relative to the rotating coordinate system.
Given that the motion along the epi-circle is perfectly circular and uniform we have that the acceleration (relative to the rotating coordinate system) is given by the general expression for the acceleration of circular motion:
$$ a_c = \omega^2r \tag{1} $$
To arrive at (2) we apply the following substitution: $\omega r=v_r$
$$ a_c = \omega v_r \tag{2} $$
As depicted in the diagram, the object goes around the epi-circle twice for every cycle of the rotating system. That is: $\omega = 2\Omega$
We use that as a substitution to make the expression independent of where the center of the epi-circle is located:
$$ a_c = 2 \Omega v_r \tag{3} $$
Summerizing:
When the centripetal force is according to Hooke's law then the terms for the centripetal force and the centrifugal term are equal in magnitude, and opposite in direction. As a consequence: in the equation of motion for motion relative to the rotating coordinate system those terms drop away against each other.
Then a single term remains: the coriolis term. Hence the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system, (the motion along the epi-circle) is described with the Coriolis term only.


In the fluid dynamics of ocean water and of the atmosphere there is a case that is the terrestrial counterpart of the motion depicted in Diagram 1.
Diagram 2. shows the origin of the centripetal force that is involved.

Diagram 2.
Buoyancy force, gravity, and the resultant (animated GIF)
We have that due to its rotation the Earth is an oblate spheroid. (The Earth started out as a protoplanetary disk, and over time contracted to its current oblate shape.)
In the diagram the oblateness is exaggerated, of course, the actual oblateness is is about 1/300 (The equatorial radius is about 20 kilometer larger than the polar radius.)
The blue arrow represents newtonian gravity, the red arrow represents buoyancy force.
On an oblate spheroid the direction of newtonian gravity is not perpendicular to the local level surface. For example, at 45 degrees latitude the deviation from perpendicular is about 0.1 degree.
Since newtonian gravity and the buoyancy force are not exactly opposite in direction there is a resultant force, in the diagram indicated in green.
That green arrow represents a force that is referred to as 'the Poleward force'. At every latitude the amount of poleward force that is present at that latitude provides the amount of centripetal force to make fluid (water, atmosphere) remain at the same latitude. Without that centripetal force all fluid would tend to flow to the Equator
The motion depicted in diagram 1. has a terrestrial counterpart. That terrestrial counterpart is called 'inertial oscillation'.
The phenomenon of inertial oscillation occurs only for mass that is subject to a force that keeps that mass buoyant. It's only with the presence of a buoyancy force that there is a resultant force, as depicted in Diagram 2. (Note especially: objects in ballistic motion are not subject to a buoyancy force.)
The phenomenon inertial oscillation (oceanography) is mentioned by the meteorologist Anders Persson in a article titled: The Coriolis Effect – a conflict between common sense and mathematics
Also available:
Discussion on my own website: Oceanography: inertial oscillations
